# Stock Status in email order opencart

Tags: opencart

Hello my opencart version in 1.5.6.4
I am trying to make stock status to appear in email order.
I tried this on catalog/model/checkout.order.php

```
$order_product_info = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product['product_id'] . "'");


'stock' => $order_product_info->row['stock_status_id'],
```

and in /template/mail/order.tpl
I have this
`<?php echo $product['stock']; ?>`

It is almost working but it appears as an id at the email. like (product_name) 5. But not appear status name...
5 s an example of stosck_status_is
Any idea on how to make it appear as text like "Available"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after you got an stosck_status_id you should retrieve from oc_stock_status table a `name` where the stosck_status_id is.

```
$order_product_status = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "stock_status WHERE stosck_status_id = '" . (int)$order_product_info->row['stock_status_id'] . "' AND language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");

'stock_name' => $order_product_status->row['name'],
```